# Релятивность Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется релятивная база данных

```
- Названия категорий
- Списки категорий
```

Вывожу названия и категории следующим образом:

```
$cat_name = DB::table('cat_name')->get();
foreach($cat_name as $row) {
$child = DB::table('categories')->where('id','=',$row->id)->get();
echo $row->title;
foreach($child as $c) {
echo $c->title;
}
}
```

Знаю то что я делаю является неверным, как правильно выводить категории?

Answer (score 2):

используйте [модели Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent), в которых задайте [отношение](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) между таблицами. Как я понял, у вас тут `cat_name`  один-ко-многим  `categories`.

Классы моделей примерно:

```
<?php // Cat_name.php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Cat_name extends Model {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

и вторая модель:

```
<?php // Category.php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model {

}
```

И вывод:

```
<?php
$cat_name = Cat_name::with('categories')->all();
foreach($cat_name as $name) {
    echo $name->title;
    foreach($name->categories as $c) {
        echo $c->title;
    }
}
```

Comment: тут уровень вложенности 2. а как повторить подобный трюк для вложенностей 3?

Comment: Можно и глубже. Если задано ещё отношение из `categories` в, к примеру, `metadata` – так же, но в модели `categories`: `public function meta(){ return $this->hasMany('App\Metadata');}`, то в запрос добавить путь через точки: `->with('categories.meta')` и циклом пройтись по `$c->meta`